# Dynamic Preview When Debugging MVC in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Perhaps this is a simple fix or setting change, but I'm looking to be able to edit the document being previewed when debugging in Visual Studio.

For example, you load a page in your MVC app and there's a debug point set in a Javascript file used by the page. Visual Studio shows you the debug stop in an uneditable preview tab with the "[Dynamic]" label and lock icon on it.

[image]

Is there a shortcut to navigate the file containing the debug stop directly as to edit the file instead of finding it inside of the solution explorer and opening it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the test, it seems that this feature is not possible, maybe you can request a feature on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest).